# Is there a "closed form" expression for the powerset of a complement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, nonstandard-models

Let us consider some consistent subset of [naïve set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory), in which a universal set $U$ exists, the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and complement $A'=U-A$ exists of any set $A$, on top of the usual binary operations $\cup$, $\cap$, $-$, $\Delta$ (symmetric difference), etc.

Considering that $\mathcal{P}(U)=U$ (as $U$ is *the* universe, rather than some arbitrary domain of discourse), since all subsets of $U$ are elements of $U$ and vice-versa,

> is there a "closed-form" expression for $\mathcal{P}(A')$?

By "closed-form" here, I mean an expression only in terms of $A$ and $U$ under the given operations (so, no set-builder notation).

An immediate answer evades me, partly because naïve set theory is often unintuitive, but also because I am sleep deprived (so I apologize If I have overlooked something trivial).

We may first ask the question of what exactly $\mathcal{P}(A')$ represents. It is not so hard to deduce that $\mathcal{P}(A')=U-\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is the family of all sets which are not disjoint with $A$. I.e;
$$\Gamma=\{x\in U:x\cap A\neq\emptyset\}.$$
If we were allowed set-builder notation, this would indeed be our answer! However, since we don't, the question becomes whether or not $\Gamma$ can be represented in some closed-form.

Equivalently,
$$\mathcal{P}(A')=\{x\in U:x\cap A=\emptyset\}$$
can be seen to be the family of all sets which are disjoint with $A$ (which is, IMO, an interesting property!). Whether this is easier to be shown to have or not have a "closed form" is not obvious to me, but worth mentioning.

Any and all advice to this recreational problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose this is a special case of the question "Does $\mathcal{P}(X-Y)$ have a closed form?" with $X\mapsto U$ and $Y\mapsto A$.

Comment: How do you even define the complement of A anyway?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The system I am using is actually a Hilbert System with operators $\{\neg, \implies\}$, in which we define $A'\iff \neg A$ and $A\implies B$ as $A\subseteq B$. (We also define $\top$ as U and $\bot$ as $\emptyset$). In this way, it turns out that a set-theoretic formula in terms of $\neg, \implies, \cdot', \subseteq$ is true iff the equivalent proposition in terms of $\neg, \implies$ is true. So the behavior of complements and subsets are described exactly by the behavior of negations and conditionals in sentential logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the universe is uncountable, and that $A$ is countable. Then any set you can build using the given list of operations is either countable or has countable complement. But $\mathcal{P}(A^c)$ has neither of these properties.

Comment: That's a great observation. Would this type of argument hold for infinite (but not "*Cantors-paradox*-infinite") $A$? (I.e; $|A|\leq \aleph_{\alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$)

Comment: Yes. In general, these operations preserve the status of having $\leq$ the cardinality or $\geq$ the co-cardinality (w.r.t. the universe) of any set.

Comment: Interesting. This eludes to some naïve set theory equivalent of the continuum hypothesis. So I suppose somewhere we have inherently invoked an analog to the axiom of choice, perhaps. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I will likely accept it after waiting a bit as-is-customary.